# Use OData FilterQueryValidator to enforce criteria like "Must Include", "Should Include"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I need to check and validate OData filter query for must include property and value.

**Ex:** Lets say for an incoming filter query,

- Must include "RegionID" in the filter, and
- "RegionID" must contain the value 5

(Of course "RegionID" and value "5" needs to be dynamically changeable, So the same filter can be used to check for other properties and values and even multiple properties and multiple values as well)

What I've been trying so far is to use a custom `FilterQueryValidator` to validate the above scenario (as mentioned here [Security Guidance for ASP.NET Web API 2 OData](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-security-guidance)). But still cannot figure out how to do it.

So my question are,

1. Is it possible to do this using `FilterQueryValidator`?
2. Is so then how can i do this using `FilterQueryValidator`? (and if possible can
   you please provide me with some sample code as a starting point).
3. If this isn't possible then how can i archive this?

#### About project

- WebAPI 2 and OData v3 (both are unchangeable)

Thanks.

**Update**

As per Fan Ouyang answer i ended up overriding both `Validate` and `ValidateSingleValuePropertyAccessNode` to check the required parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/02/06/protect-your-queryable-api-with-validation-feature-in-asp-net-web-api-odata.aspx

Scenario 8: How to customize default validation logic for $skip, $top, $orderby, $filter

In `ValidateSingleValuePropertyAccessNode` method
Check the property name through `propertyAccessNode.Property.Name`, check the operator through `binaryOperatorNode.OperatorKind`

```
var binaryOperatorNode = propertyAccessNode.Source as BinaryOperatorNode
```

Check the right side 5 at `binaryOperatorNode.Right as ConstantNode`.

I think there is enough hook and public method to achieve this, code is clear https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.Http.OData/OData/Query/Validators/FilterQueryValidator.cs

Comment: Hi Fan Ouyang, Scenario 8, is useful when trying stop filtering from a specific property. What i want to do is to force the user to enter "RegionID" property in the filter query. Ex: RegionID eq 5

Comment: you can check queryOptions.Filter.RawValue it in ValidateQuery function

Comment: yes that's what i am hoping to do if `FilterQueryValidator` doesn't pan out. I'm hoping that `FilterQueryValidator` is a better alternative than checking   `queryOptions.Filter.RawValue` and getting Regex involved.

Comment: @FanOuyang Both attached links are not valid

Comment: The first link is now located at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/protect-your-queryable-api-with-the-validation-feature-in-asp-net-web-api-odata/